# Question regarding focal loss function implementation

Tags: neural-network, pytorch, conv-neural-network, probability, loss-function

In the [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1708.02002.pdf) introducing focal loss, they state that the loss function is formulated as such:

[image]

Where

[image]

I found an implementation of it on a Github page from another author who used it in their [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2009.13935.pdf). I tried the function out on a segmentation problem dataset I have and it seems to work quite well, but the implementation seems odd to me.

Below is the implementation:

```
def binary_focal_loss(pred, truth, gamma=2., alpha=.25):
    eps = 1e-8
    pred = nn.Softmax(1)(pred)
    truth = F.one_hot(truth, num_classes = pred.shape[1]).permute(0,3,1,2).contiguous()

    pt_1 = torch.where(truth == 1, pred, torch.ones_like(pred))
    pt_0 = torch.where(truth == 0, pred, torch.zeros_like(pred))

    pt_1 = torch.clamp(pt_1, eps, 1. - eps)
    pt_0 = torch.clamp(pt_0, eps, 1. - eps)

    out1 = -torch.mean(alpha * torch.pow(1. - pt_1, gamma) * torch.log(pt_1)) 
    out0 = -torch.mean((1 - alpha) * torch.pow(pt_0, gamma) * torch.log(1. - pt_0))

    return out1 + out0
```

The part that I don't understand is the calculation of out0. Since the paper defines the Pt value when y =/= 1 as 1-p, I would have expected out0 to be written as this instead:

```
out0 = -torch.mean((1 - alpha) * torch.pow((1 - (1 - pt_0)), gamma) * torch.log(1. - pt_0))
```

instead of

```
out0 = -torch.mean((1 - alpha) * torch.pow(pt_0, gamma) * torch.log(1. - pt_0))
```

Can anyone help explain this to me?

Comment: 1 - (1 - pt_0) == 1 - 1 + pt_0 == pt_0 : )

Comment: So painfully obvious now. Thanks!